# How to get earliest of one column and get latest of another column in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by

When I run this query :

```
select * from customertravel where PersonID in (1,2,7)
```

I get this :

[image]

But I want to filter results to be like this :

[image]

How should I modify that query to  get first arrive date and last leave date? I know I need to do some group by but I couldn't figure how to use it.. Thnkas in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing your `ArriveDate` and `LeaveDate` are dates and not strings or so, you could try the following:

```
SELECT   PersonID,
         Name,
         City,
         MIN(ArriveDate),
         MAX(LeaveDate)
FROM     customertravel
WHERE    PersonID IN (1, 2, 7)
GROUP BY PersonID,
         Name,
         City;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by all columns except the dates, and find `MIN` and `MAX`. Just in case your dates are in German format you need to convert them before calculating aggregate:

```
SELECT
    PersonID,
    Name,
    City,
    MIN(CONVERT(DATE, ArriveDate, 104)) AS FirstArriveDate,
    MAX(CONVERT(DATE, LeaveDate, 104)) AS LastLeaveDate
FROM customertravel
WHERE PersonID IN (1, 2, 7)
GROUP BY PersonID, Name, City
```